# Can not create fields in ACF with code

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

This is the code i exported from the ACF when i tried to create a field via admin panel :

```
function af_barbershop_address_field() {
    if(function_exists("register_field_group"))
    {
        register_field_group(array (
            'id' => 'acf_address',
            'title' => 'Address',
            'fields' => array (
                array (
                    'key' => 'field_address',
                    'label' => 'address',
                    'name' => 'address',
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'required' => 1,
                    'default_value' => '',
                    'placeholder' => 'type the address',
                    'maxlength' => '',
                    'rows' => '',
                    'formatting' => 'br',
                ),
            ),
            'location' => array (
                array (
                    array (
                        'param' => 'post_type',
                        'operator' => '==',
                        'value' => 'barbershop',
                        'order_no' => 0,
                        'group_no' => 0,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'options' => array (
                'position' => 'normal',
                'layout' => 'no_box',
                'hide_on_screen' => array (
                ),
            ),
            'menu_order' => 0,
        ));
    }
}

add_action( 'acf/init', 'af_barbershop_address_field' );
```

I also tried to include the acf.php file into my functions.php file :

```
$acf_url = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/advanced-custom-fields/acf.php';
include_once( $acf_url );
```

All codes are in my functions file. After exporting the code, i deleted the field that created via panel and tried to create the exact same field with code, but it’s not working. What is the problem ? I’ve been dealing with this problem since last week.

Comment: Is ACF still active? The code that's exported still requires ACF to be active.

Comment: Also, you might want to check `acf_add_local_field_group()` instead of `register_field_group()`. The latter one seems to be deprecated.

Comment: @jacob-peattie Yes the plugin is still active.

Comment: @sven I tried that, but it's not working either, that function is for PRO version of plugin. I think the function that plugin exports is the right function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Action `acf/init` is available for pro version only, and I think you forgot to mention that you're using the free version because with pro version above code worked fine.

For basic version you have to use `acf/register_fields` to register your custom fields.

So you need to modify your code to:

```
function af_barbershop_address_field() {
    if ( function_exists( "register_field_group" ) ) {
        register_field_group( array(
            'id'         => 'acf_address',
            'title'      => 'Address',
            'fields'     => array(
                array(
                    'key'           => 'field_address',
                    'label'         => 'address',
                    'name'          => 'address',
                    'type'          => 'textarea',
                    'required'      => 1,
                    'default_value' => '',
                    'placeholder'   => 'type the address',
                    'maxlength'     => '',
                    'rows'          => '',
                    'formatting'    => 'br',
                ),
            ),
            'location'   => array(
                array(
                    array(
                        'param'    => 'post_type',
                        'operator' => '==',
                        'value'    => 'barbershop',
                        'order_no' => 0,
                        'group_no' => 0,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'options'    => array(
                'position'       => 'normal',
                'layout'         => 'no_box',
                'hide_on_screen' => array(),
            ),
            'menu_order' => 0,
        ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'acf/register_fields', 'af_barbershop_address_field' );
```

This should work fine. This won't work for Pro version, only earlier code would work. So you might even hook to both the actions so that in case you happen to upgrade in future the code still works.

Comment: I think they should mention in the docs that every action or function is in the pro or free version, but they don't. Thank you.

Comment: @Kumar, is this still the case? I'm able to use `acf/init` with the free version.